# Is it possible to bind into Key/Value dictionary inputs in format InputName/InputValue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to bind into Key/Value dictionary inputs in format InputName/InputValue?

Comment: What does this have to do with asp.net mvc?

Comment: I mean for exampl on html we have: 
<input type="name" value="test">
<input type="name2" value="test2">

How to bind it back to server in format
List<KeyValuePair> list where Key it is name and value it is value from html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the values in the form come and sit as `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` in action methods you have to for custom model binder.

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var form = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;  
        return form.Cast<string>().Select(s => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(s, form[s])).ToList();
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> form)
{
  ...
}
```

If you are fine with other options you can go for `FormCollection` as @Tommy suggested. By the way `FormCollection` is a built-in dictionary class that contains all the values submitted by the form.

**You can also create a simple class having properties with names as the form field names and the default model binder automatically instantiate and set the values for the class and provide to the action. This is the approach people usually follow.**

Answer (score 0):

MVC already does this if you pass the right parameter to your action method.  **Note - it is highly recommended to use strongly typed views and models in your action methods.**

With that said, if your method signature uses the following:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(FormsCollection MyFormValues)
```

Then in your code, you can use

```
var myFormValue = MyFormValues("InputName");
```

Where InputName is the key used from the FormsCollection which will give you the value that was set from the HTML.